# Show only DIVs with class x on button click

Tags: html, class, filter, show

I'm trying to get this done:

I have mutliple DIVs with some classes (let's say class-a, class-b, class-c etc.) Now I have buttons like "show-a", "show-b", "show-c" etc. 
When I click a button, I want to show up ALL DIVs that have the class and to hide ALL that haven't this class.

```
<div class="class-a class-b class-c class-d>Text</div>
<div class="class-a class-b class-d>Text</div>
<div class="class-c class-d>Text</div>
<div class="class-b class-c>Text</div>

<button>Show all A</button>
<button>Show all B</button>
<button>Show all C</button>
<button>Show all D</button>
```

Comment: The question that you are asking is too broad. We can't answer it not knowing what kind of languages you are using to flow control or simple equations. As said, I would advice to take a look in any js library/framework (javascript, jquery, angular...) were you can manipulate the DOM to do what you want (find divs with class X and add a style to not display)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<div class="class-a class-b class-c class-d">1</div>
<div class="class-a class-b class-d">2</div>
<div class="class-c class-d"
>3</div>
<div class="class-b class-c">4</div>

<button class="show-a">Show all A</button>
<button class="show-b">Show all B</button>
<button class="show-c">Show all C</button>
<button class="show-d">Show all D</button>
```

CSS:

```
.class-a, .class-b, .class-c, .class-d{
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-a").click(function(){
    $(".class-a").toggle();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-b").click(function(){
    $(".class-b").toggle();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-c").click(function(){
    $(".class-c").toggle();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-d").click(function(){
    $(".class-d").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how to automatically hide the DIVs with not clicked classes?